# Does Amos 6:10 say that the tetragrammaton "is not" to be remembered, or that it "has not" been remembered?

Tags: translation-philosophy, amos, tetragrammaton

Traditional translations say:

> "Hush!" And he will say, "For the name of the LORD **is not to be called
> to remembrance."**

Or does the Hebrew actually say:

> "Hush!" And he will say, "For the name of the LORD **has not been
> remembered."**

Which translation is correct? There's a huge difference between the two, and either result is major in implication and scope. Either the survivors did not call on the name of the LORD after the judgement, or there was judgement because the name of the LORD was not remembered!

Is the traditional rendering of this passage incorrect?

Comment: No it does not, because there we cleared up the "Hush!" part, but not the final chunk of text.

Comment: There is no need to ask for an answer in the title since that is the purpose of the site. Also, refrain from using all caps for emphasis.

Comment: Ok, I will refrain from using the capitals. The question is not getting answered by any Hebrew text people, which is frustrating because Amos 6:10 is the only verse in the entire Bible that "appears" to tell us not to say the name of the LORD.

Comment: I have no answered the earlier question.   This one should be deleted.  Please be patient.